# Releasing Excel.Applicationcom objects on application crash

Tags: c#, excel, com

While creating a simple winform (which is fetching excel values into labels & textbox) I got into this error: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Locations.xlsx' because it is being used by another process.

I just debugged to check the connectivity of my excel file... :(

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.Visible = false;
string workbookPath = tpath;
try
{
     Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
                    0, true, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                    true, true, 0, true, false, false);
     Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
     Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item("Check");
     Excel.Range excelCell = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "I11");
```

Then I realised that com object must not have been released bcoz I just tested the connectivity of the code. This makes me feel the need to release com objects if application crashes... this file is copied onto hard disk when application starts and is deleted when application closes. so there's also a need to check for releasing objects before even the file is loaded bcoz the file will be deleted.

BTW `Marshal.ReleaseComObject("Check");` is also not helping.

Any help.

**Edit:**
This getdb code goes in at 1st line of main form load.

```
         private void getdb()
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(tpath))
            {
                File.Delete(tpath);
            }
            else
            {
                string spath = textBox1.Text.ToString() + "\\Locations.xlsx";
                File.Copy(spath, tpath, true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\nSource: " + ex.Source + "\n" + ex.ToString(), "Database File Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean it "crashed"? Was there an unhandled exception? You have a `try` block there, what happens to the exceptions thrown inside it?

Comment: @BenAaronson crashed = without adding/applying a proper closing code for the excel process... I just debugged it in half coding, and since that time the process got frozen and showed "in use".

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I close it in my application:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out IntPtr ProcessId);

//close excel by the interface functions
excelWorkbook.Close(true, filepath, Missing.Value);
excelApp.Quit()

// kill the curent excel instance due to the fact that not always the curent object gets released
IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(excelApp.Hwnd); 
IntPtr processId; 
IntPtr foo = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out processId); 
Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(processId.ToInt32()); 
proc.Kill();
```

Comment: I was thinking the proper use/position of the dispose method. I'm  copying a xlsx file from network into the user desktop, also checking the existing file and removing it before I copy. I don't know when this app may face same problem so it will not be able to delete existing file raising questions at user end. SoI was wondering where exactly shud I use the dispose method and how?                    (included that simple File IO code in my question above, using it at 1st line of my main form load function)